# Find the smallest date for each ID

Tags: r

I have one data table with the following schema

```
id|smalltime
1  2199-08-02 20:00:00
2  2150-11-13 15:00:00
...
```

And I have another data table with the following schema

```
id|time
1  2199-08-02 20:10:00
1  2199-08-02 19:00:00
2  2150-11-13 15:10:00
...
```

I want to find for each id in data table two the smallest date after the smalltime of each id in data table one.

With the previous example, I am looking for the following new data table:

```
id|time
1  2199-08-02 20:10:00
2  2150-11-13 15:10:00
```

Comment: You want *the smallest date* but aren't those *the **largest** dates?* Also, post the output of `dput(df1)` and `dput(df2)` in the question, please. Or, if the data frames are too big, `dput(head(df, 20))` and the same for `df2`,  where `df1` and `df2` are the names of your df's.

Comment: I want to find the smallest date after the date of each id present in the first data table.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. But now please `dput` data examples in order for us to have something to work on and test code.

Comment: structure(list(ICUSTAY_ID = c(220597L, 211552L), CHARTTIME = structure(c(5675875200, 
4159386000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT")), .Names = c("ICUSTAY_ID", 
"CHARTTIME"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x103803b78>) This is data table two.

Comment: structure(list(ICUSTAY_ID = c(200003L, 200030L), CHARTTIME = structure(c(7245057600, 
5707638000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT")), .Names = c("ICUSTAY_ID", 
"CHARTTIME"), sorted = "ICUSTAY_ID", class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x103803b78>).  This is data table one

Comment: charteventsraw2<-setDT(charteventsraw)[CHARTTIME>charteventsraw2[HERE I WANT TO JOIN THE BOTH ID TO GET CHARTTIME OF TABLE ONE], .SD[which.min(CHARTTIME)], by = list(ICUSTAY_ID)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean to have something like below?

```r
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

df1$smalltime <- ymd_hms(df1$smalltime)
df2$time <- ymd_hms(df2$time)

df2 %>%
  inner_join(df1, by="id") %>%
  mutate(time_diff = time - smalltime) %>%
  filter(time_diff > 0) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(time = time[which.min(time_diff)])
```

Output is:

```
     id                time
1     1 2199-08-02 20:10:00
2     2 2150-11-13 15:10:00
```

Sample data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:2, smalltime = c("2199-08-02 20:00:00", 
"2150-11-13 15:00:00")), .Names = c("id", "smalltime"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

df2 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L), time = c("2199-08-02 20:10:00", 
"2199-08-02 19:00:00", "2150-11-13 15:10:00")), .Names = c("id", 
"time"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> A=strptime(df1$smalltime,"%F %T")
> B=strptime(df2$time,"%F %T")
> d=findInterval(B,sort(A))
> unname(by(B,list(d,df2$id),function(x)format(min(x),"%F %T"))[unique(d)])
[1] "2199-08-02 20:10:00" "2150-11-13 15:10:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
library(data.table)
library(purrr)

# convert to date time format
df1[, smalltime := ymd_hms(smalltime)]
df2[, time := ymd_hms(time)]

# merge df2 in df1 while grouping by df2 on id
df1[df2[, list(list(time)), .(id)], on = 'id', z := i.V1]

# check if the time is greater than df1 time
df1[, ans := map2(z, smalltime, function(x, y) lapply(x, function(j) as.character(j[j > y])))]

# extract the time (answer)
df1[, ans1 := map_chr(ans, 1)]

print(df1[,.(id, ans1)])

   id                ans1
1:  1 2199-08-02 20:10:00
2:  2 2150-11-13 15:10:00
```